# Connected entities not serialized with DataContractSerializer

Tags: linq-to-sql, serialization, .net-4.0, datacontractserializer

I am using LINQ-to-SQL and I have the Serialization Mode set to Unidirectional.

I have two entity classes, `Country` and `City`, with a one-to-many relationship.

```
DataContractSerializer serializer = 
  new DataContractSerializer(typeof(IList<Country>), new[] { 
    typeof(EntitySet<City>) // I have also tried with typeof(City)
  });
string xml;
using (Db db = new Db()) {
  IList<Country> countries = db.Countries.ToList();
  // ... some manipulation of the list here, add/remove etc ...
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
  using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(sb)) 
    serializer.WriteObject(writer, countries);
  xml = sb.ToString();
}
```

The resulting XML string has `Country` entities but no `City` entities in it.

How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `ToList()` seemed to cause the problem.